# Cómo puedo hacer un Iframe con tamaño dinámico?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Como puedo hacer que el Iframe se redimensione de acuerdo al tamaño de su contenido.

```
var ifr='<iframe  width="100%" height="auto" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen ' +' src='+src+'><iframe/>' ;
   document.getElementById("idFicha").innerHTML = ifr;
```

El iframe carga en Index.vue

```
<div class="col-lg-12" id="fame_data" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="idFicha" ></div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

En primer lugar, te propongo un codigo en javascript sencillo el cual tomara el `heigth` del contenido de la pagina que quieres cargar. Quedaria asi:

El `iframe`:

```
 <iframe id="iframe" src='+src+' width="100%" height="0" onload="resizeIframe(this)" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

La funcion `resizeIframe()` de javascript:

```
function resizeIframe(iframe) {
    iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

Esto permite que el alto del `iframe` sea ajustado automáticamente al alto del contenido dentro del mismo, y que el ancho sea de 100% de la ventana.

---

Por otra parte, existe una etiqueta html poco conocida llamada `<object>`, te explico como usar esta en vez de `<iframe>`

```
<object data='+src+' type="text/html" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

Esta seria el equivalente a lo que hice con el `iframe` pero con `object` lo que de esta forma te ahorras el javascript. El atributo `data` cargaria la pagina en cuestion y el atributo `type` especificaria el tipo del contenido.

---

Te comento que tanto de una forma o de otra, te podrias encontrar con ciertas restricciones acerca del cross-domain y debes de tener en cuenta que si lo que intentas cargar proviene de una pagina externa a la tuya, estas opciones de redimensionamiento han de estar configuradas para permitirlo automaticamente.

Hace algunos dias, respondi una pregunta sobre este problema en el que comentaba el uso de proxys y funciono correctamente a si que si tienes dudas al respecto, te lo dejo por aqui para que le eches un vistazo. [Pagina HTML5 no muestra contenido de iframe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577578/pagina-html5-no-muestra-contenido-de-iframe/577596#577596)

Un saludo y espero haberte ayudado!