# pagina HTML5 no muestra contenido de iframe

Tags: html5, iframe

estoy haciendo unas pruebas, ya que necesito que un sitio web, pueda contener partes de otra pagina web.

Esto lo quiero lograr con un iframe (no se si existe otra tecnologia que sea mejor).

El problema, es que al generar el iframe, con la url de la pagina que necesito embeber, me sale un mensaje de error en el iframe, que dice :

**La página [www.minagri.gob.cl](http://www.minagri.gob.cl) ha rechazado la conexión.**

Para que esto funcione, debo agregar algo mas??
Acá el código que estoy usando.

```
<iframe id="inlineFrameExample"
title="Inline Frame Example"
width="300"
height="200"
src="https://www.minagri.gob.cl/noticia/crianceros-de-salamanca-illapel-y-los-vilos-reciben-apoyo-ante-la-ausencia-de-veranadas/">
</iframe>
```

saludos y gracias por los comentarios.

Comment: Tal vez la página (o el servidor en este caso) tiene [activa la característica](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) que prohíbe usar `iframe` para cargar el contenido. Ante eso no puedes hacer nada.

Comment: Prueba con esto: https://tecadmin.net/configure-x-frame-options-apache/  puede que al menos sabrás por donde va el asunto. Y si puedes configurar el server mejor. https://agentbot-es-private.aivohelp.com/article/problema-rechazo-la-conexion-con-embeber-paginas-y-webviews/448098

Comment: Es como menciona @MauricioContreras, es posible que la página tenga una configuración que impide que sea mostrada en otros sitios web a través de iframes, muchas páginas web tienen configuraciones de seguridad para evitar que sean utilizadas sin su permiso y pueden mostrar un error como el que mencionas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: @OCHOA dudo mucho que el OP pueda configurar el servidor, dado que la URL es de tipo `gob`. Y a menos que el OP sea el admin de dicho dominio gubernamental (cosa que dudo mucho), las soluciones planteadas en tu comentario no son de utilidad. Saludos

Comment: Lo que podría hacer de pronto es una redirección, pero no incrustar el sitio web per se.

Comment: @MauricioContreras muy cierto, no me fije que era un .gob. Al menos la primera parte le ayudara a saber por donde va el asunto.

Comment: Buenas te encuentras ante un problema llamado CORS o restricciones de origen cruzado. Esto se debe a como bien lei en los comentarios de tu pregunta, el administrador ha bloqueado esto y la página solo permite que se cargue en un iframe si está siendo cargada desde un dominio específico. Como todo, tiene solucion. Yo te propongo usar un proxy, dejando tu iframe de la siguiente manera: <iframe src="https://mi-proxy.com/https://www.minagri.gob.cl"></iframe> Para buscar un proxy que te valga podrias usar la opcion para este tipo de problemas que te ofrece la pagina de [AllOrigins](http://allorigi

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus comentarios. Voya optar por otro tipo de solucion a traves de un scraper, y asi poder gestionar la informacion necesaria.